# Silverlight page vs user control approach

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Using which of these is the best approach while planning Silverlight application? UserControls or Page.

My understanding is that when you have to encapsulate some of the logic of some component, which is truly generic and reusable then use usercontrol else use Page because Page is tightly integrated with browser's history etc, so you can move back and forth and can make use of `NavigationService` to navigate across pages because if you keep using usercontrols, it is very tiresome to navigate all the way to the required page. Thus we cannot bookmark it because it serves no purpose. We will have to again find our way through the menus in application to reach our desired location.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. Use Pages to integrate with the Navigation framework and the main pages and controls for custom components etc.